# Should I use an API for this simple event (Express JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I havebeen having trouble with backend for a while now and Express JS has made it especially hard. However, I think I am to blame, because I've been going at with the approach that it was an **MVC framework generator** or maybe it was a framework that helps with **authentication**. But if I am correct, Express JS should reflect a RESTful API for everything. Not just for user sign up (POST) and loggin in (GET).

This is where I am kinda need clarification. From now on, is it best practice to always use RESTful API when interacting with a database? A real issue I had was with a **user** table and a **likes** table.

If a **user** clicks a **like button** on a photo, I want to do something like:

**INSERT INTO likes (user_id, photo_url) VALUES (current_user, url);**

What would the approach be to do this? How do I tell the **like button** to refer to the API? It's not like a signup form, where we give them names. Or do I just go into the Express file and start defining routes?

Comment: If you're making a RESTful API then you're going to need routes. That's how you handle your REST API calls. Then you can just send out calls either via form submission or AJAX.

Comment: Your like button makes an Ajax call.  That Ajax call must either have appropriate parameters sent with it or the cookie or session in the cookie that is automatically sent with the ajax call must already contain the necessary info (such as the user) and then you create a route on your Express server for each Ajax call you want to support.

Comment: Man, I am so stupid! You are right. I can't believe I forgot about AJAX in this situation. Thank you all so much! This answers everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you create an express route for each ajax call that you wish the client to be able to make.

Here's the general sequence of events for a Like button on a photo:

1. User logs in.  That creates some sort of state in the cookie that identifies the user (either an ID or more likely a server-side session).
2. User presses Like button on a photo.
3. Javascript attached to the Like button in the browser, gets the current photo ID and makes an Ajax call for "likePhoto" with the current photo ID as a parameter for the Ajax call.
4. The Ajax call hits an Express route that you have previously set up to handle this Ajax call.
5. If there is no logged in user session associated with this request, then the request is probably denied (probably returns some error code associated with unauthorized).
6. The Express route uses the cookie to identify the user making the request so it now has the photo ID and the user so it can make the database call to add the Like to the DB.
7. After the DB operation completes, the ajax call can return a 200 status and whatever response is appropriate.